# Moxy classpath issue

Tags: java, moxy

I have implemented Moxy for some classes in my project. But I dont want Moxy to be default for all existing classes. But the problem I am facing is that Moxy is being used for all other existing classes. How can I avoid this?

I have made sure jaxb.properties is in the same package as the classes I want it to be used for, and there is no other class in that. My package structure is like this:

> package :com.entity.a com.entity.b com.entity.c com.entity.d com.entity.d.moxy.

jaxb.properties is present in com.entity.d.moxy and all classes in com.entity.d.moxy should only use it. But all classes are picking up moxy and causing exceptions.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't have to include signature into your posts - your user card is always posted automatically at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

The `JAXBContext` returned will always come from a single provider.  Below I will demonstrate how the provider is determined with an example.

**PACKAGE #1 - forum17649220.foo**

***jaxb.properties***

This package contains the `jaxb.properties` file with the following entry indicating that MOXy is the JAXB provider (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

***Foo***

`Foo` contains a reference to `Bar`.  This means that no matter how the `JAXBContext` is created when `Foo` is processed metadata will also be created for `Bar`.

```
package forum17649220.foo;

import forum17649220.bar.Bar;

public class Foo {

    public Bar bar;

}
```

***jaxb.index***

JAXB implementations do not do package scanning.  A `jaxb.index` file can be used to enable the creation of a `JAXBContext` by package name.

```
Foo
```

---

**PACKAGE #2 - forum17649220.bar**

***Bar***

`Bar` contains a reference to `Foo`.  This means that no matter how the `JAXBContext` is created when `Bar` is processed metadata will also be created for `Foo`.

```
package forum17649220.bar;

import forum17649220.foo.Foo;

public class Bar {

    public Foo foo;

}
```

***jaxb.index***

```
Bar
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

We will create instances of `JAXBContext` a few different ways to see what is picked up as the JAXB provider.  Note that since `Foo` and `Bar` have references to each other metadata for both classes will be processed regardless of the JAXB provider used.

***Demo***

```
package forum17649220;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import forum17649220.bar.Bar;
import forum17649220.foo.Foo;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance("forum17649220.foo").getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance("forum17649220.foo:forum17649220.bar").getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance("forum17649220.bar").getClass());

        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class).getClass());
    }

}
```

***Output***

We can see from the input that whenever the `forum17649220.foo` package or a class from that package is included when creating the `JAXBContext` then MOXy will be the provider because of the `jaxb.properties` file.

```
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
```